# VBNet Error With Parameterised Database INSERT statement

Tags: vb.net, parameters, ms-access-2007, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I'm trying to send some information to a database when the "Save" button is clicked, but there are two modes, UPDATE and INSERT (for a new entry). The UPDATE statement works absolutely fine, but the INSERT satement always throws an error

```
Public Sub Save_Code()
        Dim myCon = New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Database_Job_RecordsConnectionString)
        Dim sqrtext As String

        myCon.Open()

        If Globals.Note_Add_Mode = False Then
            Dim sqr
            sqr = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Notes] SET [Category] = @Category, [Site] = @Site, [Title] = @Title, [Note] = @Note WHERE [ID] = " & Form1.NOTES_Gridview.CurrentRow.Cells("ID").Value & "", myCon)
            sqr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Form1.NOTE_Category.Text)
            sqr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Site", Form1.NOTE_Site.Text)
            sqr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", Form1.NOTE_Title.Text)
            sqr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", Form1.NOTE_Note.Rtf)


            Dim Command = sqr.ExecuteReader


        ElseIf Globals.Note_Add_Mode = True Then

    sqrtext = "INSERT INTO [Notes] VALUES ([Category] = @Category, [Site] = @Site, [Title] = @Title, [Note] = @Note)"

            Dim sqr As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqrtext, myCon)

            sqr.Parameters.Add("@Category", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Form1.NOTE_Category.Text

            sqr.Parameters.Add("@Site", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Form1.NOTE_Site.Text

            sqr.Parameters.Add("@Title", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Form1.NOTE_Title.Text

            sqr.Parameters.Add("@Note", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Form1.NOTE_Note.Rtf


            Dim command = sqr.ExecuteNonQuery() 'ERRORS HERE

        End If

        myCon.Close()

        Form1.NOTES_Gridview.DataSource.clear()

        Globals.Note_Add_Mode = False

        Screen_Starts.Initialise_Screen(6) 'Reset screen and update view

        Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

The error I am getting is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Number of query values and destination fields
>   are not the same.

I've also attempted unnamed parameters

```
sqrtext = "INSERT INTO [Notes] VALUES (?,?,?,?)"

                Dim sqr As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqrtext, myCon)

                sqr.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Form1.NOTE_Category.Text

                sqr.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Form1.NOTE_Site.Text

                sqr.Parameters.Add("@p3", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Form1.NOTE_Title.Text

                sqr.Parameters.Add("@p4", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Form1.NOTE_Note.Rtf


                Dim command = sqr.ExecuteNonQuery() 'ERRORS HERE
```

But I get the same error. However, If I add 
`sqr.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = 2`
to the beginning and shuffle the `@p#`'s up by one, the whole routine successfully executes. It's as if the AutoNumber field in the database isn't generating a number or wants something passed to it.

I've never experienced this issue before?

Comment: Also include the fields after the table in the query that those values are for.

Comment: `sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (col1, col2, col3,...colN)  VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3,...@pN)` see: [SQL INSERT](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm)  If there are more than just those 4 cols in the table, you want to be sure they are mapped correctly.  Your connection and Command object should also be disposed of, a `Using` block will do this for you

Comment: by the way, `Add()` is deprecated. use `AddWithValue()`

Comment: @Plutonix - the only other column is the deafult ID column that holds the autonumber index. I've never had to map anything to that before, Access just increments the number automatically?

Comment: @Mahadev `Add() is deprecated`  see: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @SilverShotBee,  your SQL has some text representing "Category" but without the col names listed in query, Access cant be sure *which* column to place that text into.

Comment: @Plutonix the names inside the square brackets are the column names. This appears to work OK for the UPDATE statement?

Comment: True, but it depends on which attempt in the question you look at: `"INSERT INTO [Notes] VALUES (?,?,?,?)"`  The first one isnt one of the 2 INSERT syntax formats - it looks like an edit of the UPDATE query.  See the SQL link

Comment: @SilverShotBee you should really read the link Plutonix gave in the first comment.

Comment: @Plutonix - I got it working by checking the database for the last ID number used and adding 1 to it, then putting that in to `Column 1` (ID). Thanks for your help

Comment: `INSERT INTO Notes (Category, Site, Title, Note) VALUES (@Category, @Site, @Title, @Note)`  is the correct INSERT SQL. None of them are reserved words so you dont need to escape them, the column names are in the order of the params which controls what maps to what column.  Any other cols would be DBNull except an auto-number column which Access will handle for you,

Comment: @Plutonix : Agree with your link. But VS shows deprecation warning every time i tried to use `Add()`.

Comment: @Mahadev You interpreted the msg too broadly.  See [OleDbParameterCollection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection.Add(v=vs.110).aspx) - it is only the `Add(String, Object)` form which is obsolete

Comment: @Plutonix - Thanks for the correct string, I copied it in to the code and had a Syntax error, But when I square bracketed the column names, it worked fine: `"INSERT INTO [Notes] ([Category], [Site], [Title], [Note]) VALUES (@Category, @Site, @Title, @Note)"`

Comment: Why go to the trouble of using a parameterized query for your UPDATE only to use string concatenation for the where clause?  This completely defeats one of the primary reasons for  using a parameterized query, namely, to prevent Sql Injection attacks.

Comment: Probably because it was doing my nut in and got over looked. Cheers